# infer object property type, another view on it

Tags: typescript

I'm a beginner in TS, and went through a alot of questions like this, managed to find a solution but still not sure it's the optimal one.

I'm constructing `target` object as `{obj: someObject, prop: "objectPropName"}` ... and then passing it to many different React components as a prop. `someObject` can be one of many types, about 20 different ones, each for one data model I have in my DB.
Of course, I want to do it type safely.

Ideally, I'd like to specify type of `target` as:

```
type ObjWithPropertyName = {
    obj: Record<string, unknown>,
    property: **keyof obj**
}
```

... but of course it doesn't work like that :)

Best I managed is to create a function that returns a typed target object:

```
function getTarget<T>(obj: T,propName: keyof T) {
    return {obj: obj, property: propName}
}
```

... but it looks a bit messy, especially on the receiving component side, where I need to do a similar thing again when I receive the target object as a prop.

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Please share sender and receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a generic interface for this purpose:

```js
interface ObjWithPropertyName<T> { // will work with `type` keyword too
  property: keyof T;
  obj: T;
}
```

Check it out at [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWB1YYAWAClAPYAO0YAngHJwC2EAPACoB8yA3gLABQyyMqQpRqALmQBrCFRIxkLANx8BJLBKV8Avnz6hIsRCkIl9XAB4SQAV3rpoi5FSu37UHbwQkQAZzCCJDBw8ImFKWgZmE30OAF4uNUwJTktkAEYAGicJACYtLKFycIkAcnMSrUcAeirkOGswEi96MgAbCDBgb2QAdxIoSR9kEGAkVqpkGH7kAANCkWoZviA)

Comment: Did that and it works for sending side nicely, which knows what kind of target it sends. But on receiving side (another React component that can receive any of 20 possible types of target object, via component prop)... there I cannot specify <T> because I don't know what it its.

Comment: so yes, I guess receiving side is more tricky... I need to define `target` there like {obj: *any object*, property: *must be a key of the object*}

Comment: You should make that component (as well as its props) a generic too; when you use it, you probably can omit generic parameter to it since in most cases TypeScript can infer it from usage (`<Component target={myTarget}/>` instead of `<Component<MyTargetObjectType> target={myTarget}/>`)

Comment: Wow, so much to wrap my head around. Haven't thought of that at all. I think that's the best solution possible. I made generic component and props. Codesanbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-0yqv2?file=/index.ts

Unless you find something weird in there, I think that's it

Comment: Sorry but there was a typo in my sandbox, it doesn't work after all. I get "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]" when I try to assign a value inside my Component. https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-0yqv2?file=/index.ts

Comment: In your sandbox, you are trying to assign string (and number) to an object's property, but this property is not known to be string, number, or any other type – instead object's type is `T`, and you will never know, what `T` is. You probably need to pass a value that you want to assign to the object's property into the props too, or reconsider what are you trying to achieve

Comment: yes, I realized this is a rabbit hole caused by what I'm trying to do. I realize now TS cannot just type everything. The way of designing code is affected greatly and some old habits need to change too. So i refactored and will mark this answer accepted.